# a variation of Schwarz Pick Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z, \alpha \in \mathbb{D}$
$f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$. $f(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$ is analytic, further let n be the order of the zero of $f(z)-f(\alpha)$
Prove that:
$$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(\alpha)}{1-\overline{f(\alpha)}f(z)}\right|
\leq {\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}\right|}^{n}$$

So I know how to prove without the power $n$. We first define the automorphism of the unit disk $\phi_{a} (z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}{z}}$, then we consider the function $g(z) := \phi_{f} \circ f \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} $. Then we can apply Schwarz' Lemma and then procees to get the desired inequality.

Now with the power n, (which is the order of the zero), I do not know what to change from the original proof.

Comment: show that in Schwarz lemma, if $g$ has a zero of order $n$ at the origin, then $|g(z)| \le |z|^n$ by same proof (taking now $g(z)/z^n$ and applying maximum modulus to it); then you just translate the result to the above as you noted

Comment: @Conrad: thank you very much